# Jackson serializer limit depth of 3rd party classes

Tags: java, json, jackson, serialization, fasterxml

Is there an approach to limit the serialization nesting depth of by configuring Jackson ObjectMapper or defining a mix-in? I need to be able to impose this limit for 3rd party classes, which means I cannot modify the class definitions. Also, the limit has to be generic, applicable to all classes.

I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.core, version 2.8.6

Example of limiting depth of nesting:

Consider class A, B and C:

```
class A{
    int x = 5;
}

class B{
    A a = new A();
    String y = "string";
}

class C{
    B b = new B();
    double z = 5.4;
}
```

Serialization of Class C limited to depth 1:
`C:{"b":<max_serialization_depth>, "z":5.4}`

Serialization of Class C limited to depth 2:
`C:{"b":{"a":<max_serialization_depth>, "y":"string"}, "z":5.4}`

Serialization of Class C limited to depth 3:
`C:{"b":{"a":{"x":5}, "y":"string"}, "z":5.4}`

Comment: can you give an example? how would you specify limit "depth"? by package name? by nesting level? how?